# Custom boot-up program/procedure to force shut-down based on time

Tags: startup

I would like to program a custom program or bootup procedure for my laptop that checks the computer's time, and either boots up as normal or displays a message if the current time is between X and Y,  which either forces me to shut it down, or shuts down automatically.

Can this be done, and how do I do it?

Edit: My laptop is Windows.

Comment: What OS is your laptop? I'd assume Windows based on the fact that you said laptop, but worth clarifying

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.   Yes, it's Windows.